# ASP.NET MVC generates URLS starting with '/', are relative possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

ASP.NET MVC helpers generates URLs with slash, I use `<base />` tag for my project, so it possible to place application to folder. Is it possible to generate relative URLs without first slash?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here.  Can you give a little more detail?

Comment: I used to use the <base/> tage for the same reason but, I discovered some problems with it (Can't remember what they were though) so worked out how to achieve the same effect by other means.
Could you post some examples of the need for relative URLs, so that we can suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: Here is a scenario. I want my app to work in both root of the domain and on any subfolder level. To achive that I use `<base href="http://example.com/path/to/application/">` and all other links are like this: `<a href="images/test.js">` and this will work on any folder level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax for your images...

```
<img src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Content/images/mylogo.jpg")%>"/>
```

...and all of your URLs will be calculated based upon the root of the domain, making them work in any page.

Comment: The `<base />` tag is one, but this I need to do for each and every link, which is a pain, tweaking helpers is less pain :)

Comment: Yes, I can relate to your pain. Theoretically, you could do <img runat="server" src="~/Content/images/mylogo.jpg"/> but if used in a loop, this only seems to work for the first iteration - the remainder produce <img/>. I spent a fair amount of time trying to sort this out, a while back - seems like it's time for a revisit.